# LINQ Where clause constant expression optimization

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have rewritten some of my database accessing code, in order to save some cycles. My main goal was to achieve as much server-side evaluation of my LINQ querys as possible.
In order to do so, i replaced this:

```
data = ...some LINQ...
if(condition){
    data = data.Where(element => filter-condition)
}
```

with this:

```
data = ...some LINQ...
.Where(element => !condition || filter-condition)
```

`condition` in this case is an expression that does not depend on the current element. So you could say it is practically a constant during the whole query, as it always evaluates to true for all elements in `data` or it evaluates to false for all elements.

On the other hand `filter-condition` is an expression that depends on the current element, as you would expect from you usual Where clause condition.

This optimization works like a charm, because it enables server-side evaluation in SQL on the database, and the LINQ to SQL compiler is intelligent enough to even short-cirquit the generated SQL if my `condition` evaluates to false.
My question ist, what happens if this code is not evaluated in SQL on server-side. Lets say i would do the following:

```
data = ...some LINQ...
.AsEnumerable()    //Enforces client-side query evaluation
.Where(element => !condition || filter-condition)
```

Now my Where clause gets evaluated client-side, which is not a problem on the functional side. Of course, the performance is weaker for client-side execution. But what about my custom optimization i did beforhand? Is there a performance penalty for evaluating `condition` for every element in my data sequence? Or is LINQ on client-side also intelligent enough, to short-circuit the "constant" expression `condition`?

Comment: What do you mean with "_because it enables server-side evaluation in SQL on the database_"? Linq queries are sent to the database only when they need to be materialized on the client (by example `var list = myquery.ToList()`). Otherwise you can modify them as long as you want, nothing will happen until needed.

Comment: In the second case they would be subject to [short-circuiting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) as they standard  are AND/OR operators. But the call to lambda itself will still be performed.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič You are right. The query only gets executed once its results are used. But LINQ crafts its SQL carefully, so that as much as possible filtering and mapping is already done via the SQL query on the database. But you can ofc use functions in your LINQ query that cannot be translated to SQL. Those parts of the query have to be evaluated on the client after the SQL query is answered by the database server. This mechanism is usually quite invisible to the programmer. But you can check it by looking at the SQL queries given to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is LINQ on client-side also intelligent enough, to short-circuit the "constant" expression condition?

Sort of.  `||` always gets short-circuit evaluation in C#, but LINQ on the client does not have any sort of query optimizer, so the `!condition || filter-condition` predicate will be evaluated for every entity.